# Where does animated come from when calling super.viewWillAppear(animated)?

Tags: ios, swift

In the examples I see of overriding viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool), I'm confused with the parameter passed for calling the super function:

```
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
```

I assume that "animated" is a Bool that is set to true, but where did this Bool come from? It's not declared elsewhere in my UIViewController and it isn't a property of the UIViewController.

Comment: It's in the method signature in the first sentence of your question.

Comment: `animated` is passed in by the caller to `viewWillAppear()`.  `override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` means that `viewWillAppear()` receives one value that is a `Bool` and that it will be referred to as `animated` inside of the function.

Comment: Ah - I completely understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`animated` is passed in by the caller to `viewWillAppear()`. `override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` means that `viewWillAppear()` receives one value that is a `Bool` and that it will be referred to as `animated` inside of the function.

So:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

is just passing along to its superclass the `Bool` value that it received.

**So, where does that value come from?**

When a viewController is pushed:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: false)
```

or presented modally:

```
self.present(myVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

the `Bool` value is passed to iOS to tell it how to present the new viewController.

> I assume that "animated" is a Bool that is set to true

If `animated` were always `true`, there would be no reason to have it as an input value.  It is based upon how the presenting viewController desires to present the new viewController.

If the viewController is presented with a *segue* in a *Storyboard*, the `animated` value comes from the **Animates** checkbox in the *Attributes Inspector* for the *segue*.

Comment: _never_ knew the animated parameter in how the view is animated is passed into viewWillAppear...